# How do you make an object key required in JSON Schema draft-4?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to define json schema for :

```
{
   "user_id" :{
             "default" : ["a","b","c"]
             "unknown_key1" : ["xyz","def","ekj"]
             "unknown_key2" : []
             }
}
```

The "default" key should always be present in the user_id map.
Rest of the Keys are unknown and can be any number.
Can you please help to define the JSON schema for this ?

I have defined the schema :

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "$id$",
  "description": "-1",
  "definitions": {
    "user_id": {
      "type": "object",
      "minProperties": 1,
      "patternProperties": {
        "^[A-Za-z0-9]+": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "minProperties": 1,
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "user_id": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/user_id"
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "required": [
        "v"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure how to mandate including of Default field.

Comment: what do ypu mean?please type more from problem

Comment: What have you tried so far? It sounds like you're looking for an "introduction to json schema" tutorial.

Comment: @MahdiAnjam Please see edits

Comment: @Relequestual Not looking for schema tutorial i am facing issues as i want to mandate "default" key in schema. I am facing issues in that

Comment: Your schema shows draft-4. Are you using draft-4 or draft-7 or some other version?

Comment: @Relequestual draft-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `required` keyword in the `user_id` subschema.

```
...
"definitions": {
    "user_id": {
      "type": "object",
      "minProperties": 1,
      "required": ["default"],
      "patternProperties": {
        "^[A-Za-z0-9]+": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9]+$"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  }
...
```